Plot is slow using coefficients from a large matrix
I have a matrix data with dimensions 660301 x 17, composed of Integer and Real values. Creating the plot
Plot[data[[1,1]]x^2,{x,0,2Pi}]

takes about 10 seconds (even though the value of data[[1,1]] is just 1).
If I create a second matrix of just some of the rows of data, such as tempdata=data[[1;;10]], then
Plot[tempdata[[1,1]]x^2,{x,0,2Pi}]

plots instantaneously, as one would expect.
If tempdata contains the first 100,000 rows of data, the same plot takes about 2 seconds to plot.
Why does the size of the matrix/list holding the coefficients slow the creation of the plot?

Add Evaluate. This shows the difference in timing
data = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {660301, 17}];
Dimensions[data]
Timing[Plot[data[[1, 1]] x^2, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]


data = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {660301, 17}];
Dimensions[data]
Timing[Plot[Evaluate[data[[1, 1]] x^2], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]



I tried Evaluate[data[[1,1]]] to no avail; didn't think adding the x^2
would make a difference.

On version 14.1, it does make difference. May be you are using different version? All from clean kernel each time.


I tried Evaluate[data[[1,1]]] to no avail; didn't think adding the x^2 would make a difference. Now I need to do some googling to see why this is necessary. I suppose the Plot function is reading from data for every point it plots; not sure why this is faster for small matrices vs. large

@GregH  For me, V 14.1 it is much faster when using Evaluate. Updated answer. Maybe it is difference in Version that you are using. Do not know.\

I am using V14.1. I had tried Plot[Evaluate[data[[1,1]]]x^2... vs Plot[Evaluate[data[[1,1]]x^2].... The latter is much faster. Using Evaluate for just data[[1,1]] gave about a 20% reduction in time over a regular Plot; using Evaluate for data[[1,1]]x^2 gives a 99% reduction in time.

@GregH yes, you need to include the x^2 inside the Evaluate, just like I wrote first thing above :)

@GregH When a function has a "hold" attribute, like HoldAll in the case of Plot, the whole argument needs to be wrapped in Evaluate[]; otherwise the argument won't be evaluated before the function is called, regardless of whether Evaluate[] occurs at deeper levels. For targeted evaluation, you can use With[] to inject values: With[{coeff = data[[1, 1]]}, Plot[coeff*x^2,...]].
